# ConnectionFactories for Producer & Consumer

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel. Please let me know whether the following approach is fine.

CCF for Producer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="hornetConnectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="ha" value="false"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="transportConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg
                    value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                        <entry key="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
                        <entry key="port" value="5445" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- ConnectionFactory Definition -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="hornetConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.camlin.producer" />

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-server">
        <camel:package>com.camlin.producer</camel:package>
    </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

Normal CF for Consumer,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="hornetConnectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="ha" value="false"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="transportConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg
                    value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                        <entry key="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
                        <entry key="port" value="5445" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="hornetConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.camlin.consumer" />

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-consumer">
        <camel:package>com.camlin.consumer</camel:package>

        <camel:route id="one">
            <camel:from uri="jms:queue:request?selector=type='1'" />
            <camel:to uri="bean:consumerBean?method=receive1" />
        </camel:route>

        <camel:route id="two">
            <camel:from uri="jms:queue:request?selector=type='2'" />
            <camel:to uri="bean:consumerBean?method=receive2" />
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Producers, you should use a JMS connection pool...generally either AMQ's PooledConnectionFactory or Spring's CachingConnectionFactory

for Consumers, you should use Spring's [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-mdp) over JmsTemplate.receive() where possible

see the JmsTemplate best practices: http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html

and this article for more details here: http://codedependents.com/2009/10/16/efficient-lightweight-jms-with-spring-and-activemq/

Comment: How do you configure in Camel? As mentioned in the question is this the right way to configure Consumers in Camel? Whereever I saw ActiveMQ example, the JMSComponent gets the broker URL as ctor arg. How you configure with ConnectionFactory? Because I am using HornetQ as a JMS provider